# Network printer not printing from Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: networking, printing, ping

I really need some help. I'm very new to Ubuntu and have stumbled my way through for the past 4 months after updating to a desktop that won't run Win7 and trying, but hating win10.

I have a network printer, Canon MX720, that has been printing and scanning fine - until yesterday.
The printer still works fine from my sons laptop running win10 and my wifes win7 machine.

When the printer stopped working yesterday, I deleted all the printers in Ubuntu with the intention of just setting up the printer again.

I have installed the Canon mx720 drivers via Synaptics package installer

Also I have tried using CUPS web interface - when I add printer it shows -
Discovered Network Printers:    Canon MX720 series
and I install that successful and it appears as one of the printers in CUPS.
But when i print the test page I get the message " The printer is not responding" on the CUPS Jobs list

when i ping the printer address from the Ubuntu machine , 192.168.1.99 it doesn't respond.
But when I ping it from the windows machines it does respond

I have upgraded to kernel 5.13.0.40 on Ubuntu 20.04.1 to see if it would help -despite knowing that I might run into problems doing another update - but it made things worse! It took me 2 hrs to get my multiple monitors running again.
But still not printing.

I also tried -
sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint

update -
I can't believe that after just turning on my PC today , its printing!

Whilst troubleshooting yesterday i did restart both PC and printer several times but overnight I power down the entire room - including the Ethernet Over Power devices.
Maybe these were the root of the problem.

Thankyou to the ubuntu community for the help here and the many many other posts I've read through - very much appreciate all the knowledge and experience being shared

Comment: "*when i ping the printer address from the Ubuntu machine , 192.168.1.99 it doesn't respond*" suggests a network problem more than a CUPS or kernel or other Ubuntu problem. Look for other network problems across your network.

Comment: how can you be certain the IP address is as stated? Are you using a tool such as `nmap` (which you can install [from this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-all-live-hosts-ip-addresses-connected-on-network-in-linux/)) or have you set a fixed address for the printer? If you reboot, the IP address may well change...

Comment: What's your IP address, the printer's IP address, the results of `ip route` and `arp -an`. Please [edit] your question, do not reply by "Add comment".